# Is it possible to make a circle with arrow and gradient in background?

Tags: html, css

I need to make an a circle with an arrow and a gradient inside. I know I can use it as image. But it needs to be flexible on screen resizing so that the background gradient will change dynamically. I'm curious if it's possible do this using a single `<span>` tag and CSS.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would you mind using more than just a `<span>`? How about `<div>'s` and `<span>'s`?

Comment: @Charlie - it's actually a link so i was thinking this mark-up `<a href="#"> Choose your Color <span>></span></a>`

Comment: That might be possible, I've never had great luck with border images, do you require it to be W3C valid?

Comment: @Charlie - Not necessary but it should be compatible in IE9. I make IE9 compatible gradient from here http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: You can certainly do the rounded edges with `border-radius` and the gradients with `background: linear-gradient`, if you're happy for older browsers not to get those features. But you won't be able to reproduce the shadowed, embossed, gradient-filled `>` shape without images or SVG.

Comment: Is it more likely that your user will have an uncommon browser window size or that they will be using a non-modern browser? Any of these solutions that implement CSS3 will have limited visibility.

Answer (score 7):

***EDIT:***
[image: Button css3]
Here is an example using two divs to simulate the arrow using rotation and border-radius:

### [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uboray/4/edit)

```
  .btn{
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
    font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:3px 0 3px 16px;
    text-align:center;
    height:22px;
    color:#696969;/*#DB7DB4;*/
    text-shadow:0px 1px 1px #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 22px;
    -moz-border-radius: 22px;
    border-radius: 22px;
    border:1px solid rgba(220,87,166,0.8);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px rgba(220,87,166, 0.8);

    background: #fafafa; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fafafa 0%, #939393 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fafafa), color-stop(100%,#939393)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #fafafa 0%,#939393 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #fafafa 0%,#939393 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #fafafa 0%,#939393 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top,  #fafafa 0%,#939393 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fafafa', endColorstr='#939393',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */  
  }

  .btn_circle{
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    margin:0px 3px 0 8px;
    display:table;
    width:20px;
    height:21px;
    border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    border-radius:21px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 2px rgb(92, 38, 70);
    background: #6b294f; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6b294f 0%, #BE609E 99%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#6b294f), color-stop(99%,#BE609E)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6b294f 0%,#aa6592 99%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6b294f 0%,#BE609E 99%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6b294f 0%,#BE609E 99%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #6b294f 0%,#BE609E 99%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6b294f', endColorstr='#aa6592',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
  }

  .btn_arr{
    position:absolute;
    right:8px;
    height:3px;
    width:10px;
    background:#d9d9d9;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow:-1px 0px 1px #6F375D;
  }
  .btn_top{
    top:11px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  .btn_bot{
    top:16px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
```

---

**Old post:**

[image: Button image] Here is an example of the only possible (AFAIK) css arrow:

### [DEMO 1](http://jsbin.com/ugikaw/2/edit)

### [DEMO 2 (with '>' character)](http://jsbin.com/ugikaw/6/edit)

HTML:

```
  <div class="circle">
     <div class="arrow"></div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.arrow{
    margin:0 auto;  
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
    border-left: 8px solid #CFC5CD;
}
.circle{
    display:table;
    line-height:30px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    padding:3px 5px 3px 7px;
    border:2px solid #CFC5CD;
    border-radius:21px;
   background: #6b294f; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6b294f 0%, #aa6592 99%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#6b294f), color-stop(99%,#aa6592)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6b294f 0%,#aa6592 99%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6b294f 0%,#aa6592 99%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6b294f 0%,#aa6592 99%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top, #6b294f 0%,#aa6592 99%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6b294f', endColorstr='#aa6592',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of this,

http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/kuGSw/

All it uses is, like you said,

```
<a class="link" href="#">
<span>Link</span>     
</a>
```

And then the css looks like this,

```
.link{
    background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(148,146,149,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(148,146,149,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(148,146,149,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(148,146,149,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(148,146,149,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(148,146,149,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#949295',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    padding:10px 15px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow:inset 0 -1px 0 #935E7A;
    border-width: 0px 33px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/Eepyg.png) 0 33 0 33 stretch;
    -webkit-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/Eepyg.png) 0 33 0 33 stretch;
    -o-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/Eepyg.png) 0 33 0 33 stretch;
    border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/Eepyg.png) 0 33 0 33 stretch;
}

a{
   text-decoration:none;
    color:#935E7A;
}
```

I'm pretty sure it's cross browser, I'm not sure about the `border-image`. You could possibly use @roXon's code and make a second span and then position it to the right of the text. This just uses an image.

Comment: You could use Madmartigan's code instead of roXon's for the secondary span. If you don't mind going with an image though, you could just replace it with the one from your op, http://i.imgur.com/PIBYN.png

Comment: @JitendraVyas: You can always just use your image combined with `background-size`. If you must have it looking perfect, it's the only way.

Comment: Here's an example using a `<span>` for the arrow, using the below commenter's code, http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/kuGSw/2/

Comment: Also, putting `font-family:georgia;` seems to make the `>` look nicer.

Answer (score 2):

Output: [image]

Try different fonts or unicode characters to get the arrow the way you want it to look.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/HmTYt/

Markup:

```
<span></span>
```

CSS:

```
span {
    /* Base size, adjustable */
    font-size:20px;

    display:block;
    border-radius: 4em;
    padding:1em;
    width:1em;
    height:1em;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:0 0 .25em #000;

    background: #60224b;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#60224b), to(#c45e9f));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#60224b, #c45e9f);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#60224b, #c45e9f);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#60224b, #c45e9f);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#60224b, #c45e9f);
    background: linear-gradient(#60224b, #c45e9f);
    border:.1em solid #ccc;
}

span:after {
    content:">";
    font-size:2.5em;
    position:relative;

    /* A little adjustment */
    top:-.4em;
    font-weight:900;
}
```

Comment: I like the simplicity.  You might want to do `border-radius: 50%;` -- it would make changing the size easier.  There are more [border-radius compatibility](http://css3please.com/) rules too, but they only concern a few browsers.  *edit:* if you would change that, and make a note about Unicode symbols, I can delete my answer.  They already cover a lot of the same ground.

Comment: Yeah I've never used anything but `px` personally for border radius, using `em` seems weird (maybe not fully supported) but at least it seems to adjust to the font size. Oh wait, you mean `-moz-border-radius` and such, yeah I left that out. Standard `border-radius` support seems a lot better these days, but gradients are still a pain - I just copied output from the http://css3pie.com/ demo.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one idea.  It'll need some tweaks depending on what you need.

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rQZEn/)

```
.awesome {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;

    background-color: #444444; /* Gradients + Compat */

    border-radius: 50%; /* + Compat */
}
```

Colors, sizing, etc, can all be done per what you need.

The **>** is the simplest, most obvious arrow.  It isn't the only option though.  Wikipedia lists [many more Unicode arrows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_%28symbol%29).  You'd have to cross reference them with default fonts on Windows (7?).

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it's possible in CSS3 using `border-image`.

Comment: For example : http://ejohn.org/blog/border-image-in-firefox/ ; http://alignedleft.com/blog/2010/07/using-css3-border-image-sprites-for-flexible-button-states/